# Ubuntu 14.04, apache 2.4.10. Not parse php

Tags: php, apache2, ubuntu-14.04

i have basic Vagrant box with following configuration

- Static IP: 192.168.55.155
- Ubuntu 14.04
- PHP 5.5.16
- Apache 2.4.10
- Port forward: 8081 on host to 80 on the guest system

My host system is "Windows 7" and the "hosts" file in Windows 7 contain following line "192.168.55.155 phpinfo".

I set up a basic vhost like this.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName phpinfo
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/info"
   <Directory "/var/www/info">
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I created this vhost file on my guest system "/etc/apache/sites-availble" and create a symbolic link in "/etc/apache2/sites-enabled" to my new file. After creating this vhost  i restart my apache server "/etc/init.d/apache2 restart".

If i write in my browser on my host machine the url "phpinfo", the content of my php file do not parse from the browser. It display following:

```
<?php 
    echo "hello world";
?>
```

But if i write as url "localhost:8081" the port forwarding to 80 on my guest systems work and the default host content from "/var/www/default" like "hello world" parsed from my browser.

Now i do not know the problem, because the guest system parse php on the default vhost, but not for my custom vhost.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this.

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: Ok , after i'm doing this my apache2 will not be restart. I get the following error message "AH00534: apache2: Configuration error: More than one MPM loaded"

Comment: I remove the files "/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/worker.conf" and "/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/worker.load" and restart the apache2. Now it's look like good, and it's work now

Comment: Thanks ! It really saved my time.